# Grunt build error

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Has anyone encountered the following error when using grunt build?

Going through app/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'app' of undefined). Use --force to continue.

When I comment out useminPrepare in my grunt file, it builds, but 90% 0f the images/scripts are missing

Comment: Well...the error indicates the reason: usemin is looking for `app/index.html` to build the images and scripts...but it can't and as a result the files aren't being concatenated/uglified and copied into place for distribution.  Does the site build normally, even with this warning?

Comment: I can view the site fine as I'm developing it on grunt serve localhost. Not sure where I could've gone wrong not changing app/index.html's location.

Comment: Can you update the question with (a) your usemin block from your gruntfile, (b) the `<!-- build:js js/app.js -->` and `css` blocks from `app/index.html`, and (c) your project's root-level directory structure?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Not sure what was going on inside my grunt file, but I replaced it and it builds fine!